# Summation Inequality

Tags: number-theory, inequality, summation

For which $n$ is the following true? $$\sum_{j\le n, j \text{ composite}}\frac{j}{1+\sum_{p \text{ prime factor of }j}(p-1)}\le n$$

I'm not even sure if the series converges. I don't see how to apply any results from calculus on this series, and even if it does converge, I wonder if it is at most $n$.

Comment: $\sum_{p | j} (p-1)$ is less than $C\sqrt{j}$

Comment: In mean value $\displaystyle\frac{j}{\sum_{p | j} p}$ should be something like $\frac{j}{\log^2 j}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c$ denote composite numbers and $p$ denote prime numbers.

We need to prove that $\displaystyle{\sum \limits_{c \leq n} \frac{j}{1+\sum \limits_{p|j} p-1} \leq n}$ which is just $\displaystyle{\sum \limits_{c \leq n} \left(\frac{1}{j}+\frac{\sum \limits_{p|j} p-1}{j}\right)^{-1} \leq n}$

And we want $\frac{\sum \limits_{p|j} p-1}{j}$ to be as big as possible.

$j=p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots $ to be composite must have at least 2 distinct prime numbers or a prime raised to a power bigger than 1.

Now we will deal with $j= p_1 p_2 \cdots $ with out powers because $\frac{p_1+p_2+ \cdots}{p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots} \leq \frac{p_1+p_2 +\cdots}{p_1 p_2 \cdots}$ which is easy to see.

Now for the first case $j=p_1 p_2$ so $\frac{\sum \limits_{p|j} p-1}{j} = \frac{p_1+p_2}{p_1 p_2}$ and its maximum value is $\frac{5}{6}$ (Why ?)

We have $\frac{p_1 +p_2}{p_1 p_2} \leq \frac{5}{6}$ so $6p_1+6p_2 \leq 5p_1 p_2$ divide by $p_1 p_2$ we get $\frac{6}{p_2}+\frac{6}{p_1} \leq 5$ since $p_1 \geq 2$ and $p_2 \geq 3$ so $\frac{6}{p_2}+\frac{6}{p_1} \leq \frac{6}{3}+\frac{6}{2} = 5 \leq 5$.

For the second case $j =p_1 p_2 p_3$ so $\frac{\sum \limits_{p|j} p-1}{j} = \frac{p_1+p_2+p_3}{p_1 p_2 p_3}$

We want to prove that $\frac{p_1+p_2 +p_3}{p_1 p_2 p_3} \leq \frac{p_1 +p_2}{p_1 p_2}$ multiply by $p_1 p_2 p_3$ we get that $p_1+p_2+p_3 \leq (p_1+p_2)p_3$ divide by $(p_1+p_2)p_3$ we get that $\frac{1}{p_3} +\frac{1}{p_1+p_2} \leq 1$ and since $p_1 \geq 2$ and $p_2 \geq 3 $ and $p_3 \geq 5$ so we get that  $\frac{1}{p_3} +\frac{1}{p_1+p_2}\leq \frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{2+3} =\frac{2}{5} \leq 1$.

For the third case $j =p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4$ so $\frac{\sum \limits_{p|j} p-1}{j} = \frac{p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4}{p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4}$

We want to prove that $\frac{p_1+p_2 +p_3+p_4}{p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4} \leq \frac{p_1 +p_2}{p_1 p_2}$ multiply by $p_1 p_2 p_3 p_4$ we get that $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4 \leq (p_1+p_2)p_3 p_4$ divide by $(p_1+p_2)p_3 p_4$ we get that $\frac{1}{p_3 p_4} +\frac{1}{(p_1+p_2) p_4} \frac{1}{(p_1+p_2)p_3} \leq 1$ and since $p_1 \geq 2$ and $p_2 \geq 3 $ and $p_3 \geq 5$ and $p_4 \geq 7$ so we get that  $\frac{1}{p_3 p_4} +\frac{1}{(p_1+p_2)p_3}+\frac{1}{(p_1+p_2)p_4}\leq \frac{1}{5*7}+\frac{1}{(2+3)*5} +\frac{1}{(2+3)*7} =\frac{17}{175}  \leq 1$.

For the general case $j = p_1 p_2 p_3 \cdots p_k$ so $\frac{\sum \limits_{p|j} p-1}{j} = \frac{p_1 +p_2 +p_3 + \cdots +p_k}{p_1 p_2 p_3 \cdots p_k}$

We want to prove that $\frac{p_1 +p_2 +p_3 + \cdots +p_k}{p_1 p_2 p_3 \cdots p_k} \leq \frac{p_1+p_2}{p_1 p_2}$ multiply by $p_1 p_2 p_3 \cdots p_k$ we get that $p_1 +p_2 +p_3 +\cdots +p_k \leq (p_1+p_2)p_3 p_4 \cdots p_{k-1} p_k$.

its easy to see that $p_1 +p_2 +p_3 +\cdots +p_k  \leq (k-1)p_k$, so $p_1 +p_2 +p_3 +\cdots +p_k \leq (k-1) p_k \leq (p_1+p_2)p_3 p_4 \cdots p_{k-1} p_k$. since $p_1 +p_2 \geq 5$ we get that $(k-1)p_k \leq 5 p_3 \cdots p_{k-1}p_k$.

its also easy to see that $p_3 \cdots p_{k-1} p_k \geq p_{k-1}p_k$ since all primes are bigger than $1$. so we get that $(k-1)p_k\leq 5 p_{k-1}p_k \leq 5 p_3 \cdots p_{k-1}p_k$.

divide by $5p_{k-1}p_k$ we get that $\frac{(k-1)p_k}{5p_{k-1}p_k} \leq 1$ from that we arrive at $\frac{k-1}{5p_{k-1}}$ we know from PNT that $p_{k-1} \geq (k-1) \ln{(k-1)}$ so we get that $\frac{k-1}{5 (k-1) \ln(k-1)} \leq \frac{k-1}{5(k-1)} = \frac{1}{5} \leq 1$, concluding that the **maximum value for $\frac{\sum \limits_{p|j} p-1}{j}$ is $\frac{5}{6}$**.

So $\displaystyle{\sum \limits_{c \leq n} \left(\frac{1}{j}+\frac{\sum \limits_{p|j} p-1}{j}\right)^{-1} \geq \sum \limits_{c \leq n} \left(\frac{1}{j}+\frac{5}{6}\right)^{-1} }$

And $\displaystyle{ \sum \limits_{c \leq n} \left(\frac{1}{j}+\frac{5}{6}\right)^{-1} } \geq \displaystyle{ \sum \limits_{c \leq n} \left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^{-1} }$ for all $j\geq 42$.

$ \displaystyle{ \sum \limits_{c \leq n} \left(\frac{6}{7}\right)^{-1}= \sum \limits_{c \leq n} \left(\frac{7}{6}\right) = \sum \limits_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{7}{6}\right)  -\sum \limits_{ p\leq n} \left(\frac{7}{6}\right)= \frac{7}{6}n-\frac{7}{6} \pi(n) \geq \frac{7}{6} n - \frac{7}{6} \frac{2n}{\ln n}  }  $

We want to prove that $\frac{7}{6}n -\frac{7}{6} \frac{2n}{\ln n} >n $ divide by $n$ we get that $\frac{7}{6}-\frac{7}{6}*\frac{2}{\ln n} >1$ we arrive at $\frac{1}{6} > \frac{14}{6 \ln n}$ so we arrive at $\ln n >14$ and this is true for all $n \geq 1202605$.

Note : $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function and by the PNT its asymptotic to $\frac{n}{\ln n}$ and proven to be smaller than $\frac{2n}{\ln n}$ for all $n\geq 2$.

**Conclusion : your inequality will be false for all $n\geq 1202605$ and may be by computer checking one can reduce this number.**